# How do I handle button presses in Gtk2::Image objects?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk2

I've been trying to get an `Gtk2::Image` object in this Perl Gtk2 application to get to react to button presses, but to no avail. The image shows as expected but the button events don't get handled. What am I missing?

```
  my $img = Gtk2::Image->new_from_file( $file );
  $img->set_property( sensitive => 1 );
  $img->can_focus( 1 );
  $img->set_events([qw/ button-press-mask button-release-mask /]);
  $img->signal_connect(
    'button-press-event' => sub {
      my ( $self, $event ) = @_;
      print STDERR "Coords: ", $event->get_coords;
      return;
    });
  $window->add( $img );
  $window->show_all;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GtkImage does not have any window associated to it; in other words it does not react to any X event (generally, the ones ending with `-event`).

The common way to handle events on those widgets is by [using `GtkEventBox`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkImage.html#id742894), that is placing the `GtkImage` widget inside a `GtkEventBox` and connecting X event signals to this `GtkEventBox`.